# Merging the content of an Ajax called form using WebTestCase

Tags: symfony, functional-testing, sonata-admin

I'm using the SonataAdminBundle plus DoctrineORMBundle and let's say I have a Post/Tags relationship where Tags are many-to-many to Posts.

I'm trying to run a functional test on the Post form. Tags are shown in the Post form throw an widget where the Tag form fields comes from another request (Ajax call) and merged in the Post form by Javascript.

It's easy to rely on Javascript to do this but when it comes to the functional testing 
scenario, using the WebTestCase class, I found a difficulty to simulate such functionality.

Let's say I'm testing the Create action of the Post and using this code on my test case.

```
public function testCreate() {
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client2 = static::createClient();
    //main request. The Post form
    $crawler = $client->request('GET','/route/to/posts/create');
    //second request (The Tag form) simulating the request made via Ajax
    $crawler2 = $client2->request('GET','/admin/core/append-form-field-element?code=my.bundle.admin.tags);
}
```

The problem with the code above it's that from thereon I don't know how to merge the Tag form into the Post form so this way they are submitted together.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at mink: http://mink.behat.org/

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware of Mink's existence. It's really a powerful tool but I didn't get it to work properly in my case (not because of Mink itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found how to merge those 2 request contents together. Here is code that I used:

```
public function testCreate() {
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client2 = static::createClient();
    //main request. The Post form
    $crawler = $client->request('GET','/route/to/posts/create');
    //second request (The Tag form) simulating the request made via Ajax
    $crawler2 = $client2->request('GET','/admin/core/append-form-field-element?code=my.bundle.admin.tags);
    //first request's form. This is where we'll merge the content.
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('submitButton')->form();
    //let's say we want to merge each input fields from the second request
    foreach ($crawler2->filter('input') as $node) {
       //we use the Crawler\Form::set method with a new InputFormField instance
       //that uses a DOMNode as parameter
       $form->set(new InputFormField($node));
    }

    //now we can test if the form has our merged input field from the ajax call
    $this->assertTrue($form->has('tagName'));
}
```